# Мой нож шевелится () как пьяный

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

"Мой нож шевелится, как пьяный. Ну что ж? Кто любит красный цвет? Кто хочет краски на кафтаны..."

Не могу понять, нужна перед союзом "как" запятая, так как в разных изданиях пишут по-разному. Мне кажется, что нужна, потому что это сравнительный оборот.

Поэтому интересно, как было в первоначальной редакции у Гумилева. Может быть, тогда правила были другие? Или даже по современным правилам верны оба варианта, но вот только почему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласна с Вами, я тоже вижу сравнительный оборот, а не фразеологизм. "Шевелится, как пьяный" и "шатается как пьяный", по-моему, разные вещи. Фразеологизм - о нетвёрдой походке, а здесь речь о ревности, нож ведёт себя, как пьяный человек, - неугомонный, лезет в драку, грозит отрезать соперникам носы.

В источнике - стихотворении Т.Готье на французском языке нет запятой, но её там и быть не должно, это же другая фраза, и грамматика другая, французская, а перевод Гумилёва - русский язык. Может быть, возможно объяснить различную пунктуацию разных изданий правкой корректоров - кто как видит. А как было у Гумилёва - сложно сказать.

Попыталась найти стихотворение в своих сборниках Гумилёва, но там его  нет. Надо ещё поискать на литературоведческих сайтах, пока везде по-разному, но чаще с запятой. Но ведь это тоже личное восприятие авторов статей.

Видимо, не найти нам рукописи Гумилёва и его варианта. Придётся смириться с разнобоем и субъективным мнением каждого.

Answer (score 1):

Я не нашёл ни первых изданий, ни оригинала. По-видимому, решение о постановке запятой в данном случае может принимать автор, особенно с учётом специфики стихотворного жанра. Поиск находит издание 1962 г., в котором нет запятой. Советским изданиям я склонен в данном отношении доверять больше, чем современным (в большинстве последних запятая присутствует).

В качестве возможной аргументации написания без запятой приведу цитату из монографии "Русская грамматика. Синтаксис". Я думаю, что выражение "шевелится как пьяный" в стихотворении употреблено в значении устойчивого выражения, близкого к привычному "шатается как пьяный". Строку из стихотворения несложно воспринять с ослабленной паузой и "отсутствием предикативности".

> 2) Чем устойчивее и употребительнее (в данном лексическом наполнении)
>   сочетание союза со словоформой, тем ближе его функция к функции
>   обстоятельственного распространителя: волосы торчат как ежик, одевают
>   как куколку, плачет как дитя, сладкий как сахар, вскочил как от удара,
>   бродит как во сне, шатается как пьяный; интонационное разделение при
>   этом ослаблено. В составе фразеологических сочетаний сравнительное
>   отношение лишено значения предикативности: летит как стрела, молчит
>   как рыба, стоит как вкопанный, льет как из ведра, растет как на
>   дрожжах. Разбойник мужика как липку ободрал (Крыл.).